# How can a user add an element to their profile in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a django view that should allow a user to add an anime to their profile but I'm not sure how to actually do this. The idea is that the user clicks a button that says something like 'add anime' and that adds it to a list in their profile.

I have this function called 'favorite' but so far it doesn't do anything. The idea is that it would add it to the user's profile once they make the post request.

```
def homepage(request):
   
   if request.method == 'POST':
       animes_url = 'https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime?q={}&limit=6&page=1'
       
       search_params = {
           'animes' : 'title',
           'q' : request.POST['search']
           
           }

       r = requests.get(animes_url, params=search_params)
       results = r.json()
       
       results = results['results']
       animes = []
       
       if len(results):
           for result in results:
               animes_data = {
                   'Id' : result["mal_id"],
                   'Title' : result["title"],
                   'Episodes' : result["episodes"],
                   'Image' : result["image_url"]
               }
               animes.append(animes_data)
       else:
           message = print("No results found")

       for item in animes:
           print(item)
    
   context = {
   'animes' : animes
   }
       
   return render(request,'home.html', context)

def favorite(request, pk):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       favorite = Anime.objects.get(pk=pk)
       user = request.user
       user.profile.add(favorite)
       messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Anime Favorited.')
       return redirect('home')
```

These are the models:

```
class Anime(models.Model):

   title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=150)
   episodes = models.IntegerField()
   image = models.ImageField()
   

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title

class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Anime, related_name='favorited_by', null=True, blank=True)
```

This is the html to add it:

```
<form action="/profile">
     <section>
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
         <div class="card">
           
           <div class="card-body text-center">
             <p class="card-title"> <b>{{anime.Title}}</b></p>
             <hr>
             <p class="card-text">Episodes: <b>{{anime.Episodes}}</b></p>
             
             <img src = {{anime.Image}} />
             
           </div>
     </section>
     <input
       type="submit"
       value="Add to profile"
       class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
       type="button"
   />
       </form>
```

Comment: You can create a new model `Favorite List` have foreign key of `user` and `anime`. For example: user A like anime B, table `Favorite List` have a row include user, anime, date_added in database. Then you can filter with `user_id` in Favorite List get all anime they added.

Comment: @NguyễnVũThiên Thank you, that's a good idea, I'll try that.